# PySpark: Last value of previous month by group avoiding self-join

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to obtain the last value an attribute takes per group over the previous month.

I can achieve this with a self-join like so:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = (
    spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("2022-07-29", 1, 1),
        ("2022-07-30", 1, 2),
        ("2022-07-31", 1, 3),
        ("2022-08-01", 1, 4),
        ("2022-08-02", 1, 5),
        ("2022-08-03", 1, 6), 
        ("2022-09-10", 1, 8),
        ("2022-09-11", 1, 9),
        ("2022-09-12", 1, 10), 
        ("2022-07-29", 2, 7),
        ("2022-07-30", 2, 6),
        ("2022-07-31", 2, 5),
        ("2022-08-01", 2, 4),
        ("2022-08-02", 2, 3),
        ("2022-08-03", 2, 2),  
        ("2022-09-10", 2, 8),
        ("2022-09-11", 2, 9),
        ("2022-09-12", 2, 10), 
    ],
            ["date","id","value"]
    )
    .withColumn("date", F.to_date(F.col("date")))
)

w = Window.partitionBy("id", "month").orderBy(F.col("date").desc())
df = (
    df
    .withColumn("month", F.date_trunc("month", F.col("date")))
    .join(
        df
        .withColumn("month", F.add_months(F.date_trunc("month", F.col("date")), 1))
        .withColumn("last_value_prev_month", F.first(F.col("value")).over(w))
        .select("id", "month", "last_value_prev_month")
        .drop_duplicates(subset=["id", "month"]),
        on=["id", "month"],
        how="left"
    )
    .drop("month")
    .orderBy(["id", "date"])
)
df.show()

+---+----------+-----+---------------------+
| id|      date|value|last_value_prev_month|
+---+----------+-----+---------------------+
|  1|2022-07-29|    1|                 null|
|  1|2022-07-30|    2|                 null|
|  1|2022-07-31|    3|                 null|
|  1|2022-08-01|    4|                    3|
|  1|2022-08-02|    5|                    3|
|  1|2022-08-03|    6|                    3|
|  1|2022-09-10|    8|                    6|
|  1|2022-09-11|    9|                    6|
|  1|2022-09-12|   10|                    6|
|  2|2022-07-29|    7|                 null|
|  2|2022-07-30|    6|                 null|
|  2|2022-07-31|    5|                 null|
|  2|2022-08-01|    4|                    5|
|  2|2022-08-02|    3|                    5|
|  2|2022-08-03|    2|                    5|
|  2|2022-09-10|    8|                    2|
|  2|2022-09-11|    9|                    2|
|  2|2022-09-12|   10|                    2|
+---+----------+-----+---------------------+
```

This seems inefficient to me.

Can this be done with just a window, avoiding a self-join?

Comment: your example has 2 dates per group, but what does your real data look like? does it have any dates after "2022-08-01" and before "2022-07-31"? what values should they have?

Comment: @samkart: Thanks for asking this. Yes, you can assume that there are more data both after "2022-08-01" and before "2022-07-31". I have amended my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can do it using window functions to avoid a join.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('mth', func.month('date')). \
    withColumn('blah', 
               (func.col('mth') != func.lag('mth').over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date'))).cast('int')
               ). \
    withColumn('blah2', 
               func.when(func.col('blah') == 1, 
                         func.lag('value').over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date'))
                         )
               ). \
    withColumn('last_value_prev_month', 
               func.last('blah2', ignorenulls=True).over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date'))
               ). \
    drop('mth', 'blah', 'blah2'). \
    show()

# +----------+---+-----+---------------------+
# |      date| id|value|last_value_prev_month|
# +----------+---+-----+---------------------+
# |2022-07-29|  1|    1|                 null|
# |2022-07-30|  1|    2|                 null|
# |2022-07-31|  1|    3|                 null|
# |2022-08-01|  1|    4|                    3|
# |2022-08-02|  1|    5|                    3|
# |2022-08-03|  1|    6|                    3|
# |2022-09-10|  1|    8|                    6|
# |2022-09-11|  1|    9|                    6|
# |2022-09-12|  1|   10|                    6|
# |2022-07-29|  2|    7|                 null|
# |2022-07-30|  2|    6|                 null|
# |2022-07-31|  2|    5|                 null|
# |2022-08-01|  2|    4|                    5|
# |2022-08-02|  2|    3|                    5|
# |2022-08-03|  2|    2|                    5|
# |2022-09-10|  2|    8|                    2|
# |2022-09-11|  2|    9|                    2|
# |2022-09-12|  2|   10|                    2|
# +----------+---+-----+---------------------+
```

- `blah` flags the record of the first date in a month.
- `blah2` sets the lag of `value` for the aforementioned record. i.e. `value` in the last date of the previous month.
- use `last()` window function on the aforementioned `blah2` field to fill the nulls.

Comment: Neat! I have accepted your answer as it provides the main idea. Below I have added an answer that I think solves the problem with 2 instead of 3 windows.

Answer (score 1):

[samkart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279585/samkart) has provided the main idea of the answer above. Here I provide a solution with two instead of three windows.

```
days = lambda x: x * 86400
w1 = (
    Window
    .partitionBy("id")
    .orderBy(F.col("date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
    .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -days(1))
)
w2 = (
    Window.
    partitionBy("id", F.date_trunc("month", "date"))
    .orderBy(F.col("date"))
)

(
    df
    .withColumn("value_prev_day", F.last("value").over(w1))
    .withColumn("last_value_prev_month", F.first("value_prev_day").over(w2))
    .orderBy(["id", "date"])
    .show()
)

+----------+---+-----+--------------+---------------------+
|      date| id|value|value_prev_day|last_value_prev_month|
+----------+---+-----+--------------+---------------------+
|2022-07-29|  1|    1|          null|                 null|
|2022-07-30|  1|    2|             1|                 null|
|2022-07-31|  1|    3|             2|                 null|
|2022-08-01|  1|    4|             3|                    3|
|2022-08-02|  1|    5|             4|                    3|
|2022-08-03|  1|    6|             5|                    3|
|2022-09-10|  1|    8|             6|                    6|
|2022-09-11|  1|    9|             8|                    6|
|2022-09-12|  1|   10|             9|                    6|
|2022-07-29|  2|    7|          null|                 null|
|2022-07-30|  2|    6|             7|                 null|
|2022-07-31|  2|    5|             6|                 null|
|2022-08-01|  2|    4|             5|                    5|
|2022-08-02|  2|    3|             4|                    5|
|2022-08-03|  2|    2|             3|                    5|
|2022-09-10|  2|    8|             2|                    2|
|2022-09-11|  2|    9|             8|                    2|
|2022-09-12|  2|   10|             9|                    2|
+----------+---+-----+--------------+---------------------+
```

- `value_prev_day` is value of `value` on the previous day (per `id`)
- Once we have this, we can create another partition of the data, by `id` and the month of the `date` for the current row. We then order this partition by `date`, meaning that the first of the month is the `first` row in the partition. We assign `last_value_prev_month` as `first(value_prev_day)` over this partition. This has to be last value of the previous month, since it is the `value_prev_day` of the first of the month.